# Метод dict.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача: Найдите три ключа с самыми высокими значениями в словаре

```
my_dict = {'a': 500, 'b': 5874, 'c': 560, 'd': 400, 'e': 5874, 'f': 20}
result = sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)[:3]
print(result)
```

Есть вот такая простая программа, вопрос состоит в том, что происходит когда мы выводим `my_dict.get`,а именно метод **.get** без скобок, ведь должно же быть `key = my_dict.get()`. Но если использовать скобки то результат получается не тот, который нужен

Comment: @Стас Вполне можно было бы в виде ответа оформить

Answer (score 1):

#### Ответ

- Параметр *key* принимает **ссылку** на функцию/метод, который должен применяться к элементу сортируемой коллекции перед его сравнением с другими элементами. Поэтому и скобок нет. Если бы они были, то метод вызывался бы сразу же, а его результат (вместо ссылки на метод) бы передавался как параметр *key*.

#### Объяснение

- Внимание, приведенное ниже описание является лишь описанием общего принципа работы. Фактическая реализация может отличаться. Функция, переданная параметром *key*, применяется к каждому элементу сортируемой коллекции. Потом производится сортировка преобразованной коллекции (составленной из результатов *key*). Во время сортировки новой коллекции, элементы старой перемещаются синхронно и, в итоге, оказываются отсортированы.

---

#### P.S.

Вы можете сохранять ссылки на функции/методы в переменных и вызывать их оттуда.
Например, код

```py
func = int 
func("10")
```

преобразует число точно так же, как и функция `int`